# Extending a class which contains reference to List of itself

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I have a super class something like

```
class SuperClass {
   private String name;
   private List<SuperClass> subList;
   //getter setters
}
```

And I want to extend this SuperClass to have few more field, something like

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private String email;
   //getter setter
}
```

Now, my question is since the **SuperClass** holds a reference to a list of objects of type SuperClass, how will I ensure that any **SubClass** object holds a reference to a list of object of type SubClass... is it even possible? Am I doing something terribly wrong here?

**EDIT**
Can I do something like

```
class SuperClass {
private String name;
private List<? extends SuperClass> subList;
public SuperClass(List<? extends SuperClass> subList) {
    this.subList = subList;
  }
}
```

And now SubClass just needs to call the constructor of super class

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    private String email;

    private SubClass(List<? extends SuperClass> subList) {
        super(subList);
      }
    }
```

But Now if i want to add something to the list, I would not be able to because PECS (producer-extends, consumer-super) principle of generics doesn't allow me to do that.. So whenever, i'll have to add an object to subList I will have to create a new list and then set the list in SubClass

Comment: Since SubClass **Is A** SuperClass, the construction is valid. Take a look at the classes which instantiates SuperClass and SubClass objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it be possible to introduce a third class? Something along those lines:

```
class AbstractClass<T> {
    protected List<T> subList;
    // getter setters
}

class SuperClass extends AbstractClass<SuperClass> {
    private String name;
    // getter setters
}

class SubClass extends AbstractClass<SubClass> {
    private String email;
    // getter setter
}
```

Comment: Subclass doesn't extend SuperClass..and hence it does not have **name** field in it...

Comment: Why not to move it to AbstractClass then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain that hierarchy, I would write something like this:

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    ....
    public addItemToSublist(SuperClass item){
        if(item instanceof SubClass){
            subList.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```